# UITableViewCell ImageView not scaling properly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I am populating a `UITableView` with images selected by the user.  I'd like to the have thumbnails in the table cells all be the same size without affecting the aspect ratio so as not to stretch/skew the images, which sounds to me like `ScaleAspectFill`, however none of the `UIViewContentMode` selections seem to have an effect.  There me conflicting methods, notable `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but removing this makes my cells too small.  The following are my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` methods, along with a screen shot from the simulator of my current code (using simulator stock images).  Any help is appreciated.  [image: screenshot from iOS simulator]

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //sets cell based on meme in array
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("memeCell") as! UITableViewCell
    let meme = self.memes[indexPath.row]

    // Set the name and image
    cell.textLabel?.text = meme.topText + " " + meme.bottomText
    cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill //ScaleAspectFill is best, ScaleToFill used to exagerate that its not working
    //cell.imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor() //legacy code, will be removed at commit
    cell.imageView?.image = meme.origImage

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //cell row won't be large enough unless this method is called
    return 75.0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a subclass of UITableViewCell, then overrides `layoutSubviews` method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.imageView.frame = CGRect(0,0,200,100)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities

You can use the crop function in UIImage+ProportionalFill, that scales the image proportionally to completely fill the required size, cropping towards its center,  to crop all images to the same size before assigning the image.

You can use it like this:

```
cell.imageView?.image = meme.origImage. imageCroppedToFitSize(CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
```